# How to force Espresso wait for Eventbus posts?

Tags: android-espresso, event-bus

I have Espresso test which has a lot of Eventbus posts in the implementation of the code which is being tested. I get random fails because of this asynchronous part. Is there any idea how to force Espresso to wait for this callback executions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement your own [`Espresso IdlingResource`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/IdlingResource.html) to deal with these asynchronous events.

Answer from this question: [how to make assert to wait for IdlingResource to assert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32979964/how-to-make-assert-to-wait-for-idlingresource-to-assert) might be useful.

Hope it will help